# search text in interactive ebook

Tags: android, coronasdk

I am trying to create an interactive book using corona and kwik (http://kwiksher.com).. i found that kwik will greatly help me especially on the part of the ebook layout, contents, animations & links.. but it still fall short of full-fledged interactive book, mainly the absence of search function - so i need to create it from scratch. 
my question is, how do I do it? because technically since every word in the book need to be searchable, do I need to dump all the words in the ebook into a database or I can do the search function without resorting to use of database? because obviously I will 'hardcode' all the words into the ebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) , It's pretty easy to meet your requirement.

Comment: i'm using corona (lua based) so I don't think lucene is supported

Comment: @imin  Lucene certainly support this kind of situation if only you can get words and their positions from your ebook. all you need to do is to walk through the ebook and build index. (you can still dump it into a txt file to make indexing easy)

Comment: but i'm using corona.. i googled and haven't fount any lucene implementation for corona

Comment: Then, you need to implement 'spider' by yourself

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since you asked this question, but I thought I'd shed some light into the matter. Kwik has many limitations, but it does a good job at presenting content interactively. I don't suggest using Kwik for anything else than presenting images with interactivity.

Depending on the length of your text, you may make each important key term a separate variable and create a search box that will jump to the page that the variable is in. It's messy, but you could possibly improve on the idea.

Best of luck.